# Limit to n number of tests

Tags: php, phpunit

At work we noticed the other day that we have 700 or so unit test cases, so our boss decided to offer an incentive for the author of the 1000th unit test that makes it to production.

Is there a way I can determine which unit test method the 1000th test is? The `--debug` flag doesn't provide numeration or an obvious [option](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions) like `--limit`.

Comment: what is wrong with downvoters that don't say what the issue is anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're running a Unix based environment, you could split up the debug output from PHPUnit to achieve this as it doesn't appear that there is an inbuilt option to limit the number of tests, or specify a certain test in a suite by number.

To highlight the **5th** test:

```
$ phpunit --debug | grep "Starting test" | sed '5q;d'
```

Example output:

```
Starting test 'YourTestClass::testYourTestMethod with data set #0 (1, true)'.
```